# Unfortunately, app has stopped

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

When I start my activity in the emulator of eclipse, I have the message unfortunately the application has stopped. Wish to know where the problem is, I do not understand the LogCat my logCat says:

```
06-10 21:13:06.769: I/Process(1158): Sending signal. PID: 1158 SIG: 9
06-10 21:13:21.609: D/AndroidRuntime(1197): Shutting down VM
06-10 21:13:21.609: W/dalvikvm(1197): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a96ba8)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197): Process: com.example.holamundo1, PID: 1197
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.holamundo1/com.example.holamundo1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at com.example.holamundo1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-10 21:13:21.679: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     ... 11 more
06-10 21:13:25.819: I/Process(1197): Sending signal. PID: 1197 SIG: 9
```

The code is:

```
  package com.example.holamundo1;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.*;
  import android.view.*;
  import android.widget.*;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button miBoton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    miBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Botón presionado!");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
   }
```

Comment: What is line number **15** in `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: There seems to be null pointer exception. Post your code

Comment: check whether your views existing in your inflating layout and initialized with correct `id`.

Comment: **com.example.holamundo1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)** there is the error

Comment: its a null pont exception, so u make sure that (R.id.button) id of button.Also check is this in the activity_main

Comment: post `activity_main.xml` and `fragment_main.xml` if you have them. Lot of new users end up in the same problem

Comment: if reference to button id is correct then simply clean you project and build. Sometime R file is not generated properly.

Answer (score 0):

First Check that your `Button` is imported as `import android.widget.Button;`

Second thing that check your `Button` is in your `activity_main.xml` file with the id of `R.id.button`

Comment: import android.widget.*;

Comment: Have you seen my second line? And i have just told him to check.

Comment: yes i see that, i just want to say second part of your answer is correct, because i think OP use fragment and this button exist on fragment layout.

Answer (score 0):

`activity_main.xml`  should have a button widget with ID as "`button`"

`miBoton` is **null** because probably, there is no widget with the ID "`button`" in `activity_main.xml`

Either **rename** the button id defined in the xml as "`button`"

Or

**Use the button id defined in the xml**, say if it is defined in xml as button1, then in your code use it as `R.id.button1`

Answer (score 0):

define the button Id in your activity_main.xml file.